# Parsing Python array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, python-2.7

I have a Python script running on my server that creates a 2D list like so:

```
[['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3'], ['2012-09-10 00:11:00', '61.3', '57.0'], ...]
```

I pass this back to the PHP script which is running my webpage. Here's the PHP I'm currently using to get the array. I get the rows, but obviously with an unwanted `[[` at the start and `]]` at the end.

```
exec("python weatherdata.py $stationID $startdate $enddate", $pyoutput);
$vars = explode("], [", $pyoutput[0]);
```

For the sake of explaining what I actually want to do, since there's bound to be a "proper" solution (I'm not at all familiar with PHP), what I want to do is adapt the code from [here](http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/creating-downloadable-csv-files/) which download a CSV file to the user, but uses mySQL to populate it. The set-up part here works fine.

**Edited in response to Jack's answer below**

```
// Commented out my working parsing part
// remove the start and end square braces then split into rows
//$output = str_replace("[[","",$pyoutput);
//$output = str_replace("]]","",$output);
//$rows = explode("], [", $output[0]);

// output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='data.csv');

// create a file pointer connected to the output stream
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

foreach (preg_split('/],\s*\[/', trim($pyoutput, '[]')) as $row) {
        $data= preg_split("/',\s*'/", trim($row, "'"));
        fputcsv($data);
}
// Commented out my working write to CSV part
// write rows
//foreach ($rows as $row){
//    $row = str_replace("'","",$row);
//    $row = explode(",", $row);
//    fputcsv($output, $row);
//}
```

Comment: If you can have Python output the array with double quotes instead of single quotes, you can just `json_decode()` it without modification. Try and use an interoperable standard for this, JSON seems ideally suited.

Comment: This seems like the right way to go. I'll see if it's possible - although could it also be done as a string replace at the PHP end?

Comment: I'll answer that myself - yes it can `$output = str_replace("'",'"',$output);`

Comment: That is not a safe option. Consider `['Some string with a \' quote in it']` - the data will be modified. Does Python not have a json encoding function?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: Yes, simplejson and json. Reading up on them now, although I'm fairly sure there won't be any escaped single quotes in this data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure whether this is viable for you, but since PHP 5.4 it supports the [short array syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-82), e.g. `[1, 2, 3]` instead of `array(1, 2, 3)`.

So, you could just use evil ... I mean `eval()`:

```
$vars = eval(`python weatherdata.py $stationID $startdate $enddate`);
```

Otherwise, if the array syntax is always in that format, just break it apart with `preg_split()`, first on square brackets and then on single quotes:

```
foreach (preg_split('/],\s*\[/', trim($s, '[]')) as $row) {
        $data = preg_split("/',\s*'/", trim($row, "'"));
        print_r($data);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Header1
    [1] => Header2
    [2] => Header3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2012-09-10 00:11:00
    [1] => 61.3
    [2] => 57.0
)
```

Comment: Thanks but that's giving me an internal server error, I assume because not the right version of PHP.

Comment: @jamiebull updated it, assuming the strings will be "simple" :)

Comment: Thanks. I've cracked it now though. I would have used @Dave Random's json approach but it turns out my host doesn't include json as part of the pre-installed packages - which took hours of pointless going in circles to figure out. In the end I went with remove "[[", remove "]]", explode on "], [", foreach row, write each row, parsing it as you go along. Hacky as can be but it's working.

Comment: @JamieBull isn't that basically the second part of my answer? :)

Comment: It may well be. As I said, PHP's new to me (like, yesterday new). I'd actually missed the second part to your answer. I just had a quick go at implementing it your way and I'm sure the problem's at my end. Should I be passing in my `$output` as the `$s` variable in your snippet then writing to the CSV with `fputcsv($data);` beacause that's outputting a blank CSV?

Comment: @JamieBull I'm not sure which `$output` you mean though, because there's one from the `exec()` but you're also opening a file with variable `$output` :)

Comment: Sorry, the one from the python. I've renamed it `$pyoutput` in my working version to keep things clear.

Comment: @JamieBull For testing, I've used this string value `"[['Header1', 'Header2', 'Header3'], ['2012-09-10 00:11:00', '61.3', '57.0']]"`.

Comment: Not working for me with the test string either. I've edited the question to show what's working for me (in comments) and to add your code that's not quite doing it. Really appreciate your time on this.

Comment: @JamieBull `fputcsv($data);` ... you forgot to pass `$output` as the first argument :)